# VueJs - Deleting a File-input component from a list

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I'm still pretty new to vue.js.
I recently created some vue components to tidy up my html. The components are different inputs like `text` and `checkbox`. They update the parents data using `$emit('input', val)`. And make sure that the `components` are up-to-date using `props` and `watch()` on those `props`.

Now there is a problem with using `watch()` on `<input type="file />`, since you cannot set the input value like you can on other input types.

Using this example:
https://jsfiddle.net/minde281/nyu73dz6/25/

I have a list of, in this case, items on a shoppinglist. You can add an image for each item.

The image is loaded and added to the list. This works fine.

To get my problem:

- add an image to *item1*
- delete that item by clicking the X-button

The result is now that *item2* will have that image on the `<input type="file" />`. The preview works as expected since this can be set through script and therefore use `watch()`. But somehow vue removes the wrong part of the `html markup` causing the last one to be removed.

Is there a different way to solve this problem? Or is there a way to tell vue to remove the correct part of the html markup?

-Minde

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Vue tries to reuse the component and thats why the selected file is in the second input after deleting the component.

To prevent that you should use the key binding like this:

```
 <li v-for="(item, index) in items" :key="item.name">
```

Now the hole component gets removed and everything should work as expected.

Comment: Tank you. Fast and easy answer.